# error with Corefoundation in Libjingle compile

Tags: macos, gcc, core-foundation, libjingle

I am trying to build libjingle on OSX 10.6.8 with xcode 4.3  and have run into and error with corefoundation which is killing the process. I assume the problem is with it not seeing corefoundation (or any other framework for that matter) though I've have no idea how what the actual include path should be to fix this.  Thoughts?

```
./swtoolkit/hammer.sh  
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: warning: The build_dir keyword has been deprecated; use the variant_dir keyword instead.
File "./../swtoolkit/site_scons/site_init.py", line 203, in BuildEnvironmentSConscripts
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
________Compiling build/dbg/obj/base/macasyncsocket.o
base/macasyncsocket.cc:12:43: error: CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/anurodhp/Development/libjingle/talk/base/asyncsocket.h:32,
                 from /Users/anurodhp/Development/libjingle/talk/base/macasyncsocket.h:15,
                 from base/macasyncsocket.cc:15:
/Users/anurodhp/Development/libjingle/talk/base/sigslot.h:81:16: error: list: No such file or directory
/Users/anurodhp/Development/libjingle/talk/base/sigslot.h:82:15: error: set: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/anurodhp/Development/libjingle/talk/base/socket.h:46,
                 from /Users/anurodhp/Development/libjingle/talk/base/asyncsocket.h:33,
                 from /Users/anurodhp/Development/libjingle/talk/base/macasyncsocket.h:15,
                 from base/macasyncsocket.cc:15:
```

Comment: fixed it. Oddly the main.scons file that comes with jingle needs to have isysroot correcly set. '-isysroot', '/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk',